# Omit bucket folders from page urls - linkprovider not working in SXA

Tags: sxa, buckets, link-manager

I created a custom item resolver to remove/omit bucket folder item name from url.
With this resolver we can access url from:

- www.xpto.com/folder/2018/08/06/15/40/page
- www.xpto.com/folder/page

And it works properly.

But when I create a link in a rich text for this bucketed page, the bucket path is not omited.

I followed this blog post:
https://sitecorejunkie.com/2016/05/31/omit-sitecore-bucket-folder-item-names-from-page-item-urls/

Seems exactly what I need but it's not working for me.

I'm using Sitecore 9 (and SXA).

Comment: What does your config look like when patched? (what's the output of showconfig.aspx - for the linkmanager section)

Comment: @Gatogordo

https://image.ibb.co/dGnX3z/print.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of SXA is rather important in this case.

As you can see in your configuration, SXA uses by default the `switchableLinkProvider`. This will check your site configuration in Sitecore to determine if you defined a linkprovider there. If not (I assume you did not), it will take the fallback, which is defined here:

```
<setting name="XA.Foundation.Multisite.FallbackLinkProvider" value="localizedProvider" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.config"/>
```

As you can see, the default fallback is the localizedProvider and not "sitecore". So you are actually patching the wrong provider.

To fix this, you could patch the `localizedProvider`, but I wouldn't do that. I'd rather add a new provider to the list and attach that to your site in SXA. How to do this can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/add_and_select_a_custom_link_provider : navigate to *sitecore/content/tenant/site/settings/Site Grouping/site* and in the Basic section, in the Link Provider name field, enter the name of your custom provider.