# SXA - Search Results - Render link url lowercase

Tags: sxa

Is there any way to have the search results component render links in lowercase?
I have patched the linkManager as follows

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <add name="sitecore">
      <patch:attribute name="languageEmbedding">never</patch:attribute>
      <patch:attribute name="lowercaseUrls">true</patch:attribute>
    </add>
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Perhaps the search results link is coming from the index it's not respecting that setting?

Sitecore 9.1.0
SXA 1.8

Comment: Under settings for the tenant have a look at the site grouping item. There you should be able to override the link provider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omit bucket folders from page urls - linkprovider not working in SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13242/omit-bucket-folders-from-page-urls-linkprovider-not-working-in-sxa)

Comment: In my opinion the question is very different, but your answer is valid for both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many components in SXA use the `switchableLinkProvider` whether you specify this via the `defaultProvider` or not. However not all code in SXA uses the `switchableLinkProvider` directly, some will still use the LinkManager which uses the configured `defaultProvider`. See [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26829/1278) for more details.

The [documentation here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-and-select-a-custom-link-provider.html) shows how to change the linkManager provider per site. In this case, simply changing it to "sitecore" should work as it will pick up the values you've patched on the `sitecore` provider originally.

[image: highlight location]

**BUT** it would be better to change the `defaultProvider` back to `switchableLinkProvider`, update the settings you need on the `localizedProvider`, and update your site to explicitly use the `localizedProvider`.

Comment: Note that with this solution, you need to change this on all your SXA sites..  otherwise you should patch the localizedProvider.